# Laravel 5.0 Selective Append or MorphThrough Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, polymorphic-associations, eloquent

I know the subject is a little bit confusing. Let me explain.

For a medical software that I am currently developing, I have a data structure as below:

**Patient**s has **Protocol**s. **Protocol**s has **Examination**s, **Prescription**s or **Report**s, all polymorphic.

In some cases, I have to directly access to the **Examination**s of **Patient**s. However, since this includes a polymorphic relation between **Examination** and **Protocol**, I cannot directly setup a relation method in my **Patient** model.

As a work around, I can set a custom `getExaminationsAttribute` and append this with `$appends` in **Patient** model. But this causes a whole load of data fetching when I try to get ,for example, only the `name` of a **Patient**.

Any help is appreciated.

**Patient** model:

```
class Patient extends Model{
    protected $table = 'patients';

    public function protocols(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Protocol', 'patients_id', 'id');
    }

    protected $appends = ['examinations'];

    public function getExaminationsAttribute()
    {
        $examinations = array();

        $this->protocols->each(function($protocol) use (&$examinations){
            $protocol->examinations->each(function($examination) use (&$examinations){
                $examinations[] = $examination->toArray();
            });
        });

        return $examinations;
    }
```

**Protocol** model:

```
class Protocol extends Model{
    protected $table = 'protocols';

    public function patient(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient', 'patients_id', 'id');
    }

    public function examinations()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Examination', 'protocolable');
    }
```

**Examination** model:

```
class Examination extends Model{

    protected $table = 'examinations';

    public function protocols()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Protocol', 'protocolable');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, `patients_id` column added to submodels of **Protocol** table (**Examinations**, **Prescriptions** etc.) and will be fetched via `hasMany` relationship.